# IntelliJ fails to recognize stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar file

Tags: intellij-idea, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford nlp to do sentiment analysis. I just need the sentiment score therefore following are the libraries that I'm adding into my project:
1) ejml-0.23.jar
2) stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar
3) stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar

When I add dependencies in the Project Structure in IntelliJ, first two work fine and are imported correctly and shown in the external libraries tab. But for the models.jar it throws me an error saying that IDEA cannot determine what kind of files the chosen item contains. When I still go ahead and add it - I don't see the models.jar file in the External Libraries section. See pics attached:

Libraries present in my Project Structure:
[image: Libraries present in my Project Structure]

External Libraries: models.jar not included
[image: External Libraries: models.jar not included]

Comment: It is likely that the jar file might be corrupted. Are you able to inspect the contents of the jar file manually? You may do it with any archive reader (7zip etc.) tool as jar files are actually zipped files with `.jar` extension.

Comment: Yes, I am able to inspect the contents of the jar file manually. Any ideas on how should I get it to work on IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

`stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar` is not a library of Java classes but instead, it contains various nlp models that are used by different algorithms in the core package.

Therefore IntelliJ fails to recognize the content (which is fine). As long as the jar file is available in the classpath at the runtime, you should not run into any issues. It seems the case by looking at the project structure so I would not worry about this particular error.

Comment: Actually I was not able to run it at all on IntelliJ. However I got it working on Eclipse without doing anything extra. Beats me why it would work on one ide and not the other one. Anyways, thanks for your help.